# Can't compile and execute java program

Tags: java, cmd, javac

I have the following simplified file structure:

`C:/red/green/black/yellow/white/pink`. I am now in cmd in folder 'black'.

The `Hello.java`file has `package yellow.white.pink` in it. In folder 'pink' there is a `Hello.java` source file.

First I try to compile the file:

`javac -classpath . -encoding ISO-8859-1 yellow.white.pink.Hello.java`

`javac -cp . -encoding ISO-8859-1 yellow.white.pink.Hello.java`

These two give me an error:

`File not found yellow.white.pink.Hello.java`.

Then I try

`javac -encoding ISO-8859-1 C:/red/green/black/yellow/white/pink/Hello.java`

It compiles just fine.

To run it I do

`java -classpath . yellow.white.pink.Hello`
And it runs just fine.
But in this case

`java C:/red/green/black/yellow/white/pink/Hello.class`

doesn't work - gives `Could not find or load main class` error.

Why is that? Why can't I compile .java file when being in the root folder and giving a full package name and it works only with the whole path to the source, while the reverse is true for executing the program?

Comment: You compile source files by giving the path to the file, not the package name.

Comment: @Dave Newton, So is this correct: When compiling a `.java` file you can be located in cmd in any folder on your computer, while when running the `.class` file using `.packagename.ClassName` command you need to be located in a folder prior to the first one of the `packagename`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java` command takes as an argument the fully qualified name of the class (which is package name plus class name).

In both cases the fully qualified name must be `yellow.white.pink.Hello` and it should not be changed.

However in your second run you pass `C:/red/green/black/yellow/white/pink/Hello.class` which is path to the compiled file but not the fully qualified name of the class.

What is also different in this two runs is `classpass` declaration. In the first run it is path of the current directory (can be passed as `.`). In the second run it was not specified at all. Java treat this as current directory path.

To make the second example work you have to specify `classpath` as well as class name.

`java -classpath C:/red/green/black yellow.white.pink.Hello`